# CollectionView - Respect bounds for one section but not for other section

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I have a collection view which is using compositional layout with 2 sections. One section is horizontal and one is vertical. The vertical section is having boxes with shadows and rounded corners and needs to have ClipsToBounds set to false due to cut off issues. However, the horizontal section needs to be cut off and follow the bounds. How can I accomplish this? Is the best solution to add a vertical frame with clear background and place on the right side or is there any better solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Did you use the [CollectionViewCompositionalLayoutsAndDiffableDataSources](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/ios13/UsingCollectionViewCompositionalLayoutsAndDiffableDataSources)?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT No I'm not, would that have helped solving the issues with ClipsToBounds for different sections ? I'm feeding the datasource with 2 different types, one for each section.

Comment: But the ClipsToBounds is used for all the subview. So adding a vertical frame you mentioned should be a good idea.